# let "this" scope on find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
$(this).parent().find('.nameValue').replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
```

Now I want to set the value of the input to the text from ".nameValue". But the "this" selector scopes onto the click event, causing that the inputs value is the value from the button I clicked.

This worked:

```
$(this).parent().find('.nameValue').each(function() {

    replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
});
```

But I dont really need the each function. So I hope there is a better approach. I Hope you understand what I mean - Im not a native english speaker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a function callback:

```
$(this).parent().find('.nameValue').replaceWith(function(){
      return '<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">'
});
```

You can't avoid a function callback to bind `this` to the current element or assign a variable to the current element on each iteration.  You must have some way to refer to the current element as you iterate on them to retrieve the value you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: I have no clue why this was downvoted. It worked. And I think its the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

> But I dont really need the each function

You do.

The value of `this` is determined on a per-function basis, so you need a separate function to be applied to *each* element that you find.

Comment: Thanks, so I assume there is no other way? I mean, what would I do, if I had no Jquery?

Comment: @MyNameisKev — Probably use `querySelectorAll(selector).forEach( function () { ... } )`